# What is the most basic, primitive, barebone way to accepts input into a node process?

Tags: node.js, input, command-line-interface

I'm new to Node interfaces and building a comprehensive CLI is not my priority, but I've been playing with a few options here like `inquirer.js` and `prompt` and `commander`. At this point, I'd really like to know if I can forego all of this, even [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline) and just call *something like* `process.argv` 
conditionally in some parts of my code because the logic is not that complicated.

Does node expose anything like that?

Is `readline` the most basic one can do?  Thank you!